# find character array length in Android

Tags: java, android

to get length of string

```
String str=strLenData.toString();
int ipLen= str.length();
return ipLen;
```

whatever be the value of `strLenData`, value of `str`= *[C@40523f80*. As a result, for every char[] I input, the length is shown as 11.

I have to use the length as a limit to a loop. Many a times the actual length of char [] would be less than 11. In those cases, the application crashes with the `java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`.

Is there any other method to find the length of array. In C++ we might look for `'\x0'` to mark the end of string. But I guess that is not valid case in Android.

Comment: What array is throwing the exception: strCharData or replaceThis?

Comment: replaceThis[j] to be exact...

Comment: That seems unlikely unless you are changing the value of j in 'do something'. I suggest posting a stack trace of the error

Comment: 'do something...' comes after 'if(strCharData[i+j]==replaceThis[j])'. The app exits at 'replaceThis[j]'. The 'if' condition should be passed atleast once which is not the case. It's not even working for j=0, which is the first condition.

Comment: you should have to post some more code. I am totally blank.

Comment: The posted code does not compile and if fixed does not throw any exceptions. Please post an SSCCE (SSCCE.org).

Comment: @Andro Selva: This is the problematic part of code. There is an outer `for`loop i.

Comment: @SkipHead, I didn't get your point.

Comment: If ever you find that you may have asked the wrong question, just flag for a moderator and ask us to close or remove it, you can then ask the question that you really meant to ask. This prevents people from leaving answers that become immediately dated once the scope of the question changes.

Comment: What's the *question?* The length of any array 'a' is given by 'a.length'. You appear to be doing 'a.tostring().length()', which gives you something else entirely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
String str=strLenData.toString();
int ipLen= str.length();
```

I assume strLenData is a char[]:

This code calls toString() on a char[], which returns garbage (I think it's something like a 2 char indicator of the data type + the hashcode of the array but that's not important). You then take the length of that String which is 11.

if strLenData is a char[] then you get the length with strLenData.length. It's a field not a method so there is no ().

Answer (score 0):

May be other code from the same line (may be `strCharData[i+j]`) goes out of bound

Comment: nope... it doesn't...  when i log the value of strCharData[i+j],it does not give any error. but when i log the value of replaceThis[j], it throws the error. my main concern is that i can't afford to ignore this statement...

Comment: post the exact code which produced this also indicate the line number in that

Comment: the whole code does not fit into the "comments" portion given here... I think this would be ok... coz there is no code between the lines i stated...

Comment: try printing `strCharData.length` ,`i` &  `j`  .

Comment: errors were not expected by logging these :) what are the values for each

Comment: then how come the app throws same error when i logged 'replaceThis[j]' and not when i logged 'strCharData[i+j]'???

Comment: what are the values for each parameter. in general arrayindexoutofbounds occours when you try to access out of bound

Answer (score 0):

The problem might be because of this,

```
strCharData[i+j]
```

Consider the length of strCharData to be 5. 
Now if you can see, you have used "i+j". Consider the result of i+j to be greater than 5. 
This will lead to a situation where you are referring to an index which is greater than the length of strCharData(say 5).

Or even this **replaceLen** value might be bigger than the total array size. Check it out

Comment: while allocating the array size, i have used dynamic array allocation: new char [expected string length]... so this shouldn't cause any problem.... replaceLen is a temporary kind of array...

Comment: as far as I know, arrayindexoutofbounds occurs if you are trying to point out a location which is actually bigger than the amount of size you have provided. so what I have suggested is only one possibility here. So you have to check for each and every variable size you have used.

Comment: if that was the case, then the error should be thrown in the first line itself!!! if(strCharData[i]==replaceThis[0]) . but that's not the case... what is the difference between j=0, replaceThis[j] and replaceThis[0] ? Logically (in my opinion) they mean the same right?

Comment: no that's not true. you will get this error only when the length exceeds the size. so obviously you will get this error after few iterations inside for loop.

Comment: there are no iterations... believe me.. i have written the log and value of j is 0 when the application throws exception

Answer (score 0):

Java throws an out of bounds exception when you access an array outside its limits. In Java an array goes from 0 to length - 1.

In your case I would guess it is because replaceLen is too big, but could you please post the entire method so we can see?

Comment: replaceLen can be max of size 2... not more than that... and also, it's working for replaceThis[0]

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using char arrays to do replacement? It's likely that you're better off using String.replaceAll, which accepts a regex. The regex can handle the 'match' part of your code and the replacement string doesn't have to be the same length as long as it matches the regex.

As Andro mentioned, the problem is almost definitely due to the i+j exceeding the bounds of the array and you're better off not using arrays at all.

Comment: the problem is NOT with i+j coz i wrote LOG for each statement separatly... and it did not throw any error when i printed i+j

Comment: I want to write a common code (a very small part of business logic) for android, iPhone, .NET, since C is the native language for all of these, I am using C syntax. This is to maintain the uniformity of code across the different platforms...